# Can't install Internet Explorer 9 in Windows 7 x86

Tags: windows-7, windows, internet-explorer

I need Internet Explorer 9 for developing. So I go [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/internet-explorer-9-details.aspx) and I can download it only for Windows Vista and Windows Server 2008. However when I try to install I get the error (translated):

```
This version of IE install program doesn't support this version of Windows.
```

How can I fix that?

Comment: @Ramhound I have IE8

Comment: [Download test VMs of IE for OSX, Linux or Windows](https://www.modern.ie/en-gb)

Comment: Also by pressing F12 in IE11 and clicking the computer/tablet icon you can emulate IE 5/7/8/9/10.

Comment: @Ramhound No. As I think it will try to install IE11

Comment: @Ramhound Do you mean I should enable windows auto update?

Comment: @Ramhound I've just installed this win7 in VM as I use only centos.

Comment: @Ramhound I don't trust MS auto systems. Do you? That's why I didn't want it to do more I need (IE9). But, I've enabled windows update (I choose what to install). But it's already 2-3 minutes it's in progress - it's searching the updates. Is it normal?

Comment: @Ramhound It's over. Results: IE11, security updates, .net, sp1.

Comment: @PashaTurok - Given the amount of security holes that exists in an unpatched Windows installations I place more trust in Microsoft than the people who don't trust Microsoft and do silly things like using old versions of IE and NOT update their installation.  You really should install Service Pack 1 that will be required for IE9.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some research on the web I found the offline installer [download link](http://download.microsoft.com/download/C/3/B/C3BF2EF4-E764-430C-BDCE-479F2142FC81/IE9-Windows7-x86-enu.exe) of Internet Explorer 9 for Windows 7. And the [localizations download link](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/internet-explorer/downloads/ie-9/worldwide-languages).

Also be sure to check and install the [Internet Explorer 9 prerequisites](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2399238/en).

Comment: Thank you!!! It's working. This (bad words) microsoft do everything in order we hate it. I can't upvote your answer as I don't have here enough reputation. Thank you again.

Comment: You're welcome. By the way Microsoft isn't that bad ;)

Comment: You even can't imagine how many hours of my life I wasted because of this ... company products such as IE8 etc.

Comment: @PashaTurok - You could have just used the free VM that Microsoft provides with IE9 already installed.